# How does Task.Factory run our commands?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have a code like this:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // go run my web service 1
});

RunMyWeb_Service_2();
```

So what can happen here? Is it possible that first it goes and my second web service and then comes back and runs my first web service? Is there a way to tell it first run my first web service ( well except taking it out of the threads!).

Comment: Well presumably they're going to execute in parallel. Isn't that the whole point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want them to run in parallel (concurrently) you can use this.

```
Parallel.Invoke(
    () => RunMyWebService1(),
    () => RunMyWebService2()
);
```

That will run both web service calls at the same time. If Web Service 2 is dependent on the result of Web Sevice 1, you can use `ContinueWith`.

```
Task.Run(() => RunWebService1()).ContinueWith(task => RunWebService2());
```

Or alternatively, you can run them in reverse.

```
Task.Run(() => RunWebService2()).ContinueWith(task => RunWebService1());
```

**Update**

If you need them both to run at the same time, but on a worker thread, you can wrap the Parallel.Invoke in a Task.

```
Task.Run(() =>
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => RunMyWebService1(),
        () => RunMyWebService2()
    );
);
```

Both web service calls will be ran at the same time, in a background thread.

**Update for .NET 4.0 solution**

The [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is still available for use in the .NET 4.0 framework. Since Task.Run is a 4.5 only feature, we just need to modify our usage of the Task object. The following will create a background worker thread and run both web service calls concurrently.

```
var webServiceCalls = new Task(() =>
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => RunMyWebService1(),
        () => RunMyWebService2()
    );
);

webServiceCalls.Start();
```

This will require the first webservice call to finish before starting the next.

```
var webCalls = new Task(() => RunWebService1())
    .ContinueWith(task, => RunWebService2());

webCalls.Start();
```

Comment: "ContinueWith".. very interesting. Will give it a shot.

Comment: It will run the entire process on a worker thread, but not allow the task in `ContinueWith` to execute until the first Task is completed. You can daisy chain these _n_ number of times.

Comment: Oh! My RunWebService1 is very heavier. I need it to run on its own thread(s)

Comment: On it's own thread, after the 2nd web service call is completed or at the same time as web service call 1? Are they dependent on one-another?

Comment: They are not dependent but still I need first one to finish first on its own thread. Plus I don't know why but I don't have a Run method in Task method.

Comment: If they are not dependent, take a look at my update. You can run both of them concurrently on a background thread. If you don't want the 2nd call to happen until the 1st call is finished, then you _must_ use the `ContinueWith` approach. If the 2nd call can be made at the same time as the 1st, then the new example I provided should help. As for your missing Task.Run, make sure you have System.Threading.Tasks in a using statement. Are you using .NET 4.5? It is a feature in 4.5. Otherwise I will have to update my example with a non 4.5 solution.

Comment: Yes I am on .NET 4.0 for this project. It will be awesome if you could update your sample codes for .NET 4.0 when you get a chance. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a .NET 4.0 example. Please check out the link I added as well for additional details on the TPL library.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible that first it goes and my second web service and then comes back and runs my first web service?

Sure.  You now have two threads executing these two methods.  They can do their work in any order whatsoever.  The second method could do all of its work before starting the first, the first could do all of its work before starting the second, the first could do have, then the second do half, then the first, they could each do 1/100th of their work in a back and forth manor.  You have no idea whatsoever what order any given sub-task of either operation runs in with respect to the other, nor do you have any idea which one will finish first.

If you want them to be executed in a particular order either do them on a single thread, or, using the TPL model, you can schedule one operation as a continuation of another, which ensures it won't start until the task it is a continuation of finishes.